# Use input-submit to represent multiple options

Tags: html, forms, submit

I have a table of events on a page. Last column contains available actions, i.e. "accept", "tent. accept", "cancel".
So if you are an attendee you'll get "accept"/"tent. accept" buttons. If you are the organizer you have "Cancel" option.

Now, I have done "Cancel" as `<input type='submit'...` element, and put "accept"/"tent. accept" as links. That's not actually bad, but still pretty evil. I'd rather use input/submit consistently, but still keep one-click operations (i.e. I don't want to have selection-box AND a submit button).
**Assume user has JS disabled.**
Should I create two forms for accept/tent case? or is there a better solution?

E.g. Bob will see:

```
| Topic | Time | Organizer | Actions  |
| Stuff | 2:00 | Bob       | [Cancel] |
```

And Jane, who was invited on the same meeting, will see:

```
| Topic | Time | Organizer | Actions                |
| Stuff | 2:00 | Bob       | [Accept] [Tent. Accept]|
```

**Question** again is: How do I implement two buttons for Jane's choice, so that each button is still a `<input type='submit'...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names (and values) of your submit buttons should be available to your server-side script so that you can take different actions.  Here's a full explanation: http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/html-form-submit.phtml

Answer (score 1):

you can use it with one form. Differenciate it with the name

```
<form action="" method = "post">
<input type='submit' name = "sub_button" value="Cancel">
<input type='submit' name = "sub_button" value="Accept">
<input type='submit' name = "sub_button" value="tent">
</form>

if($_POST['sub_button'] == 'Cancel') {
....
} else if($_POST['sub_button'] == 'Accept') {
....     
} else if($_POST['sub_button'] == 'tent') {
....
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. tehMick was simply first.